# iron router : How to check parameter _id matches the meteor.userId()

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

Objective: 
How to query the parameter _id that matches the Meteor.userId() before executing the downloadReport render. Please refer the below script and advise.

```
Router.route('/myReports/:_id/:area', {
    name: 'myReports',
    waitOn:function(){
      return false;
    },
    onBeforeAction: function(){  
        if(Meteor.userId()){
          this.next();
          ***this.render('downloadReport', {to:'myReports'});***
        } else {
          this.next();
          this.render('tabbedLogin', {to: 'myReports'});
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by query? You want to get _id value from the route? If so try:

`this.params._id`

Answer (score 1):

The route parameter `:_id` is available in js in the route as `this.params._id`. Just do:

```
onBeforeAction: function(){  
  if( this.params._id == Meteor.userId() ){
  ...
  }
}
```

[documentation](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#route-parameters)